# mysql. How to select the last date for each hour

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have stock market data in a mysql database. I'd like to find the closing trade price for each hour.

I've come up with this query:

`SELECT MAX(date), price, FROM tradetable WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-01-25 23:00:00' AND '2014-01-28 12:59:59' GROUP BY hour(date) ORDER BY date;`

However my results are not ordered by the date properly. It's jumbled up. The hours and days are not in order.

What am I doing wrong?

Returned data:

2014-01-27 02:59:59 --- 815.37000
2014-01-27 03:59:59 --- 813.00000
2014-01-27 04:59:59 --- 808.59998
2014-01-27 05:59:59 --- 812.07001
2014-01-27 06:59:59 --- 816.00000
2014-01-27 07:59:59 --- 825.84998
2014-01-27 08:59:59 --- 824.00000
2014-01-27 09:59:59 --- 825.50000
2014-01-27 10:59:59 --- 828.91998
2014-01-27 11:59:59 --- 820.00000
2014-01-27 12:59:59 --- 816.90002
2014-01-27 13:59:59 --- 821.20001
2014-01-26 14:59:59 --- 822.88000
2014-01-26 15:59:59 --- 819.00000
2014-01-26 16:59:59 --- 817.79999
2014-01-26 17:59:59 --- 817.78003
2014-01-26 18:59:59 --- 819.98999
2014-01-26 19:59:59 --- 816.66998
2014-01-26 20:59:59 --- 822.15997
2014-01-26 21:59:59 --- 819.52002
2014-01-26 22:59:59 --- 820.00000
2014-01-26 23:59:59 --- 816.00000
2014-01-27 00:59:59 --- 825.39001
2014-01-27 01:59:59 --- 821.90002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
GROUP BY DATE(date), HOUR(date)
```

You're combining times from different days in the same group.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(date), price, FROM tradetable WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-01-25 23:00:00' AND '2014-01-28 12:59:59' 
GROUP BY hour(date) ORDER BY date, time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to select max(date) group by date and hour, then join that result back with tradetable to get price for each hour.

```
SELECT T1.date,T1.price
FROM tradetable T1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DATE(date) as tradedate,
            HOUR(date) as tradehour,
            MAX(date) as maxtime
     FROM tradetable
     WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-01-25 23:00:00' AND '2014-01-28 12:59:59'
     GROUP BY tradedate,tradehour
    )T2 
ON T1.date = T2.maxtime
ORDER BY T1.date
```